# Make the http request wait to return its response

Tags: typescript, promise, angular5, httprequest, guard

I have a HTTP GET request that returns a permission. I use this request in my auth.service.ts in isProjectLead(). I need to wait for the http request to return the value to allow access to a page.

How can I do this? I tried to use Promises, but I don't know much about it.

```
get isProjectLead() {

  var flag = false;
  //var thisPromiseCount = ++this.promiseCount;

  var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  if (!this.selectedProject) {
    this.selectedProject = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  }

  this.linkService.getLinksByUserAndProject(user.username, this.selectedProject).subscribe(links => {
        this.links = links;

        this.links.forEach(element => {
          if (JSON.parse(element).role.id == "2") {
            flag = true;
          }
        });
      },
        (err: any) => {
        });


  return flag;
}
```

Comment: This code should be working already. The code within 'subscribe' should only get executed when `getLinksByUserAndProject` returns data. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: I know but I need to return the flag as true. The http get request is finishing after the return. I never get the flag as true, so the access is always blocked. @Kokodoko

Answer (score 0):

## Convert the observable to promises

```
async isProjectLead() {

  var flag = false;
  //var thisPromiseCount = ++this.promiseCount;

  var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  if (!this.selectedProject) {
    this.selectedProject = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  }

  try {
    var links = await this.linkService
      .getLinksByUserAndProject(user.username, this.selectedProject)
      .toPromise();
    this.links = links;

    this.links.forEach(element => {
      if (JSON.parse(element).role.id == "2") {
        flag = true;
      }
    });

  } catch (e) {
    // handle error
  }

  return flag;
}
```

### Point to remember

The return response is also going to be a promise so you have to wait for the promise to resolve.

Comment: Thanks so!! My request is returning Observable<string[]>  (return this.http.get<string[]>(url);)! How do i convert/write it to promise?

Comment: I have updated the answer to return the promise. Please see the ```.toPromise()``` action after the service action call.